# How to initialize a Matrix of Matrices with the right dimension?

Tags: julia

I would like to create a `n x m`-dimension Matrix of `k x k`-dimension Matrices (containing zeros).

How can I do that in Julia?

Comment: The output you wanted does not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet-Another-Answer, to complement the already beautiful ones above.

```
repmat([zeros(k,k)], n,m)
```

(or its more syntactically flexible cousin `repeat([zeros(k,k)], outer=(n,m))`)

**EDIT: This seems to be the fastest method by far**
I will put benchmarks below:

---

**BENCHMARKS:**
(from fastest to slowest)

```
k = 2; n = 3; m = 4

julia> @time for i in 1:10e4; A = repmat([zeros(k,k)], n,m); end
  0.601392 seconds (2.80 M allocations: 112.915 MB, 1.49% gc time)

julia> @time for i in 1:10e4; A = fill(zeros(k,k), n,m); end
  1.053698 seconds (200.00 k allocations: 27.466 MB, 0.13% gc time)

julia> @time for i in 1:10e4; A = repeat([zeros(k,k)], outer=(n,m)); end
  1.217569 seconds (6.10 M allocations: 222.778 MB, 1.97% gc time)

julia> @time for i in 1:10e4; A = [zeros(k,k) for i=1:n, j=1:m]; end
  8.217551 seconds (2.83 M allocations: 214.951 MB, 0.19% gc time)
```

Comment: The added advantage of `repmat` is that it will be instantly recognizable and loved by octave / matlab users :p

Comment: i suspect you did the benchmarks in the global scope, the benchmark on my machine shows `fill` is the fastest, `repmat` and `comprehension` are quite the same(about 6x slower than `fill`).

Comment: @GnimucK. yes, that's right! That's very interesting to know; how does global vs local scope affect this case?

Comment: here are some references: [performance tips](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/?highlight=benchmark#avoid-global-variables) & [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/8870).

Comment: This may not do what you expect: try setting `A[1,1][1,1] = 1` then look at `A` (also, it only works on 0.5 or later).

Comment: RangerBob, @SimonByrne has made an excellent point about underlying objects being copied rather than created with fill and repmat, so this solution is wrong. Please accept his answer instead so I can remove mine.

Answer (score 6):

n-d comprehensions are probably easiest:

```
[zeros(k,k) for i=1:n, j=1:m]
```

Update: You need to be careful here: presumably you want to fill the array with *different* matrices of zeros: the other proposed solutions (`fill` or `repmat`) will actually give you an array where all the entries are the same zeros matrix, e.g.:

```
julia> k = 2; n = 3; m = 4; A = fill(zeros(k, k), n, m)
3×4 Array{Array{Float64,2},2}:
 [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]
 [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]
 [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]

julia> A[1,1][1,1] = 1; A
3×4 Array{Array{Float64,2},2}:
 [1.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [1.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [1.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [1.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]
 [1.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [1.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [1.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [1.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]
 [1.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [1.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [1.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [1.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]
```

Comment: I've done some benchmarks out of curiosity (see below). Turns out list comprehensions in julia are a bit slow in comparison. :/

Comment: I wonder why it is so much slower. I don't know why list comprehensions would be so much slower than the other methods (Good work @TasosPapastylianou!).

Comment: It depends how you time it: try putting it inside a function: `foo(k,m,n) = [zeros(k,k) for i=1:n, j=1:m]`

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have to say, while there's a clear warning for `fill` in its documentation, I would classify this as a bug for `repmat`, as a *single* evaluation is very unlikely to be what the user intends; (at least not unless explicitly specified). This seems like the kind of function that was included for the benefit of people migrating from matlab without too much thought on how it might break in julia.
Thanks for the catch; I'll remove my answer and submit a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

I also use something like this

`fill(zeros(k, k), n, m)`

Comment: This doesn't quite do what you expect: try `A[1,1][1,1] = 1`, then look at `A`

Comment: Ahh good catch. I didn't realize it would stick `n` by `m` Pointers to the same matrix in the matrix.